# Is there any way that we can know the video in embedded player is age restricted?

Tags: ios, youtube-iframe-api

I am using [IFrame Player API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference) from Youtube in my app, and for age rating concern I need to know if the video is age restricted or not.

I am not going to use data api for this. Is there any way that I can know the video is age restricted or not ONLY by using IFrame Player API?

Comment: yes check here 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12940901/youtube-api-2-0-checking-if-a-video-is-age-restricted

Comment: @AbuUlHassan Thanks! But that's using data api. I want to get it only from ifame  player api though...

Comment: in that case i have not found it yet, why dont you send an email to support? for this query?